# Google Calendar to sign into centralized account, not individual user's account

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I'm building an app that needs to maintain a set of calendars for its users. However, the calendars should be tied to the (single) google account of the app, and not the personal individual accounts of the users.

Moreover, since the calendars belong to the app and not the users, the users should not have to authenticate anything.

Is it possible to do this using the Google Calendar API? I'm using their API v3 for PHP, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible. Save the refresh token for the app calendars in your server, client wont interact directly with the calendar api, instead goes through your php server which does the api calls.